# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when doing a JDBC read from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space message when reading from an 11g Oracle database via JDBC.  I have the defaultRowPrefetch set to 10000, reducing it to 2000 seems to resolve the issue.  However, adding additional memory to the JVM (-xmx) does NOT resolve the issue.  This issue only seems to occur in 64-bit java 1.6 - I was not seeing this issue in 32-bit java.

My question, what setting can I change to allow my application to run with the larger defaultRowPrefetch?

Comment: Heya keith, default defaultRowPrefetch ist 10, I got strong improvements by setting it to 250. I think even 2000 is very high compared to the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're editing the correct setting (although it's `-Xmx`, not `-xmx`), but it sounds like you need to increase it further, e.g.

`-Xmx256m`

As far as the 64 bit thing is concerned, you'll find that a 64bit JVM uses up heap *much* faster than a 32bit JVM (which makes sense, the pointers are twice the size), so a 64bit JVM needs more heap anyway.

Comment: -XX:+UseCompressedOops helps to reduce the heap size on 64-bit JVM's, with a slight performance penalty incurred.

Answer (score 1):

Can't out of memory also come form a lack of PermGen?  More to memory than just heap

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Comment: It can.  But if it does' the OOME's error message will *tell you* that you are out of permgen space.  If it doesn't tell you, you would be wise *not* to twiddle that particular knob!  Besides, permgen space is *unlikely* to be relevant to reading a JDBC resultset.